# Recommended Nginx Configuration for High Traffic Website on Wordpress

Tags: centos, nginx, wordpress, errors

We have a Wordpress based website that gets about 1.5 million pageviews per day. Maximum concurrent sessions reach up to 5000 users per minute at times.

We have one web and one database server. Specs for both machines are as follows:

```
CPU: 2 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650 @ 2.66GHz
12M Cache / 6 Cores / 12 Threads (x2)
Memory: 24GB
Drive(s)(size/GB) - 4x240gb SSDs RAID 10
```

We run on Nginx, use FastCGI, and also use APC for caching, along with simple page caching with WP Super Cache.

Current Nginx configuration is as follows:

```
worker_processes  24;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;
worker_connections  4000;
```

FastCGI settings are as follows:

```
FcgidMaxProcesses 200
FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
MaxProcessCount 100
FcgidIOTimeout 400
FcgidIdleTimeout 600
FcgidIdleScanInterval 90
FcgidBusyTimeout 400
FcgidBusyScanInterval 80
ErrorScanInterval 3
ZombieScanInterval 3
```

Server fails and we get Nginx errors (502-504) during high traffic. I am wondering if this is related to a bad configuration.

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something like CloudFlare?

Comment: @ceejayoz We have used it in the past with little success, and even more errors. Which brings me to some lacking/bad config on our end.

Comment: @kce I don't believe it would be a duplicate since I am trying to solve consistent server generated errors which I suspect are related to misconfiguraton. Technical specs of the system in question should be more than enough for the amount of traffic we register.

Comment: Where are your bottlenecks? What analysis have you done already?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
FcgidMaxProcesses 200
```

This directive sets the maximum number of FastCGI application processes which can be active at one time. I think it's low for your traffic. The default value for this is 1000.